# How do you work with NFTs on Anchor?

Tags: anchor, nft

I'm trying to mint an NFT using Anchor but the current docs are out of date. Does anyone have a simple example?

Answer (score 2):

Hey there with anchor you can add mpl-token-metadata to your cargo.

```
mpl-token-metadata = { version = "*"}
```

make sure you import:

```
use mpl_token_metadata::{
    state::{Creator, Collection},
    instruction::{create_metadata_accounts_v3, create_master_edition_v3}
};
```

So a very basic example would be:

```
...
#[account(mut)]
initializer: Signer<'info>,
#[account(
    init,
    payer = initializer,
    mint::authority = auth,
    mint::freeze_authority = auth,
    mint::decimals = 0
)]
nft: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>
#[account(
    init,
    payer = initializer,
    associated_token::mint = nft,
    associated_token::authority = initializer,
)]
nft_ata: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
#[account(mut)]
///CHECK: account is initialized in the ix
metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
#[account(mut)]
///CHECK: account is initialized in the ix
master_edition: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
#[account(
    mut,
    seeds=[b"auth", config.key().as_ref()],
    bump = config.auth_bump
)]
///CHECK: This is safe. It's just used to sign things
auth: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
mpl_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
....


impl<'info> ...<'info> {
    pub fn issue_nft(
    &self
) -> Result<()> {
    let accounts = MintTo {
        mint: self.nft.to_account_info(),
        to: self.nft_ata.to_account_info(),
        authority: self.auth.to_account_info()
    };

    let seeds = &[
        &b"auth"[..],
        &self.config.key().to_bytes()[..],
        &[self.config.auth_bump],
    ];

    let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];

    let ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        self.system_program.to_account_info(),
        accounts,
        signer_seeds
    );

// Mint NFT
    mint_to(ctx, 1)
}

// Create Metadata
    let create_metadata_ix = create_metadata_accounts_v3(
.....
//In case you have a collection and you added a collection acc
Some(Collection { verified: false, key: self.collection.key() }),
...


 // Create Master Edition
    let create_master_edition_ix = create_master_edition_v3(
....
```

If you want to do a collection, you would need to add a collection account To the account struct. Mint this collection nft, create the metadata and master edition( its existence is proof of the Non-Fungibility of the token). Then after minting the nfts you need to pass the collection account, set the collection when creating the metadata.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a simple localhost [example repo](https://github.com/prasmalla/deviant).

Specific setups have been broken down into separate commits.

*Note: It uses older **mpl-token-metadata** (v1.13.1) and has the NFT metadata JSON stored on GitHub as centralized storage for modification.*

Open to PRs to get this to use latest version!